# Convert "2017-10-31 20:42:00" string to timestamp in Apache Hive

Tags: csv, hadoop, hive

I have recently uploaded a csv file to Apache Hive table and the file has 3 Columns with timestamps

```
start_time,end_time,last_updated
"2017-10-23 11:07:00","2017-10-31 20:27:02","2017-10-31 20:27:02"
"2017-10-17 09:54:00","2017-10-23 10:51:02","2017-10-23 10:51:02"
```

Once I uploaded the same file to Apache Hive it is taking all these columns as strings and I tried to make these columns as timestamp data type but the values become NULL.

I also tried doing type casting but that did not help!

I really wanted them to be timestamp.

click [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Types#LanguageManualTypes-CastingDates) for type casting that i have gone through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `unix_timestamp` and cast it to `bigint`

```
select
  cast(
   unix_timestamp("2017-10-23 11:07:00","yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") as bigint
   )
```

Returns `1508782020` . When you want to convert it into date use

`select from_unixtime(1508782020, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')`

Returns `2017-10-23 11:07:00`